# Why is there a deadlock in kotlin pipeline code

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, pipeline

```
class PipelineExecutor<T>() {

    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)

    fun execute(vararg jobs: Job<T>)
    {
        var inputChannel = Channel<T>()
        var outputChannel: Channel<T>
        val wgroup = CountDownLatch(jobs.size)

        jobs.forEach { job ->
            outputChannel = Channel()
            scope.launch {
                job.run(inputChannel, outputChannel)
                wgroup.countDown()
                outputChannel.close()
            }
            inputChannel = outputChannel
        }
        wgroup.await()
    }
}
```

this code doesn't work

For a long time I can’t get the code to work, it needs to asynchronously call a method on the functions supplied as input, but somewhere a deadlock is caught

Comment: What is your job API ? By the look of it, a job waits a signal from an input channel to start working, no ? But in your example, no signal is pushed to the input channel, so I do not think it can work. Your first job will never start. Also, CountDownLatch should not be required. You should just have to wait signal on the last output channel.

Comment: API
`fun interface Job<T> {
    suspend fun run(input: Channel<T>, output: Channel<T>)
}`

Comment: the problem is not that the signal does not arrive, I am artificially taking the first step of the pipeline 
`internal fun testExtra() {
        val freeFlowJobs: Array<Job<Int>> = arrayOf(
            Job{input: Channel<Int>, output: Channel<Int> ->
                output.send(1)
            },
            Job{ input: Channel<Int>, output: Channel<Int> ->
                for (value in input) {
                    output.send(value * 3)
                }
            }
        )
        val executor = PipelineExecutor<Int>()
        executor.execute(*freeFlowJobs)
    }`

Comment: I've tried the same locally, and the program runs and end successfully (I've added println to ensure all jobs successfully run and end). Does the deadlock appear with your `testExtra` test, or with more evolved jobs ?

Comment: Also, note that default dispatcher is not always recommended. Maybe try with another one, for example `Dispatchers.IO` or one you create yourself: `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(N).asCoroutineDispatcher()`